# tomcat db2-jdbc datasource configure

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc, db2

i'm trying to configure a datasource of an db2 database in tomcat (using eclipse as IDE), but i cant solve the problem, Tomcat trow me the following exception:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1136)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at com.azurian.lce.usuarios.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:65)
    at com.azurian.lce.usuarios.db2.UsuarioDAOImpl.autenticar(UsuarioDAOImpl.java:101)
    at com.azurian.lce.usuarios.UsuarioServiceImpl.autenticar(UsuarioServiceImpl.java:31)
    at com.azurian.lce.web.admin.actions.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:49)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1130)
    ... 23 more
```

where i put the jdbc files of DB2? i try in every place (in the libraries of the project, in the lib folder of the tomcat install directory, in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the Dinamic Web Project, in the tomcat classpath in the eclipse "tomcat server" configuration an so far)

Regards

ps.: I'm using:

DB2 9.7
Tomcat 6
JDK 1.6
Eclipse Galileo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put it outside Eclipse in the `/lib` folder of Tomcat or in any of the paths as specified in the `shared.loader` or `common.loader` properties in `/conf/catalina.properties`. If it doesn't solve the problem, then it is not the right Tomcat instance you think Eclipse is using.

If everything went well (dropping the JDBC driver in server's library), then you should see it show up in the *[ProjectName]/Java Resources (src)/Libraries/[ServerName]* listing in the Project Explorer.